# Posting Open Graph user action on Facebook APP Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, feed, facebook-page

I have a website which involves posting of user's activity on the website to the facebook fan page of the app(post are done using logged in users identity). I have managed to post on the facebook user's timeline as well as the facebook fan page.

Since I wanted to include link of the website's page in the feeds (goes to two pages.. user's timeline and facebook fan page). Therefore I thought, open graph would be a better option in this scenario.

On using open graph, I realized that I can post the user's action on user's timeline but I was unable to post to the fan page. I'd like to know how do I go about posting on facebook fan page? Is it not possible to use open graph in this case.

PS: Also before using open graph I used link parameter while posting  as feed, but then  the like counters for that link used to increase by 2 since I was sharing that link twice. Since I wanted to avoid this from happening, I hoped open graph would solve this problem for me.

Comment: Is any one out there with a solution to this problem or is my question vague and I need to reframe it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible, because Open Graph actions are actions done by *a user* which show up on their timeline.

It is a reflection of their activity so as such, the only reasonable place for it to show, would be on their timeline to their friends. Posting on another timeline/ fan page is no longer an action but a feed post.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Right now I am posting a feed on the facebook app page because of this issue. Have you got any idea of how I can post a link to the facebook page without increasing the like counter? Since facebook is giving me issues while posting link in the message